# Open two flutter modules from native

Tags: ios, flutter, module, communication

I am trying to open two different flutter modules from our native iOS app, which has many feature written in swift and working. Now we want to build two new features in `Flutter`. For that we need to open two different modules or methods of flutter from native iOS code.

I've tried many solutions but no luck. Here are **two sample flutter methods** I've created which in future will trigger route for two different feature:

```
//First Method
class MyFirstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to My First App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World 1'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Second Method
class MySecondApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to My Second App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World 2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's one `route` I tried to write in flutter:

```
class RouteState extends StatefulWidget {
  RouteState({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _RouteState createState() => _RouteState();
}

class _RouteState extends State<RouteState> {
  static const apiChannel = const MethodChannel('my_channel');

  Future<dynamic> handleMethod(MethodCall call) async {
    switch(call.method) {
      case 'first':
        return MyFirstApp();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello World 0'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now from iOS I'm trying to open any of the above method in one `viewcontroller` of native codebase.

```
let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).flutterEngine
let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my_channel", binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
channel.invokeMethod("first", arguments: "")
//viewController.show(flutterViewController, sender: viewController)
```

But nothing is happening, not opening anything from here. No logs are printed for any error either. I've debugged in both sides, break-point is reaching all the code in iOS side and in flutter side everything is fine. When I run only flutter module with a `main()` it worked. But not opening from native.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `present` in your code. As stated [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=vc-swift-tab#show-a-flutterviewcontroller-with-your-flutterengine)

try this:

```
let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).flutterEngine
    let flutterViewController =
        FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    present(flutterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes I did that earlier, it's good if you have only one module, and that is working for me also, but I am confused how I shall handle two different module with that.